# How do you draw an antialiased circular line of a certain thickness? How to set width on pygame.gfx.aacircle()?

Tags: python, pygame

Like `pygame.draw.circle(Surface, color, pos, radius, width)`, I want to get antialiased circle.

But, there is no option about width on `pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle()`.

Anyone knows alternative way?

Answer (score 2):

Neither the [pygame.draw](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html) module nor the
[pygame.gfxdraw](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/gfxdraw.html) module provide a function for an antialiased circle with an scalable thickness. While [`pygame.draw.circle()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) can draw a circle with different width, [`pygame.gfxdraw.circle()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/gfxdraw.html#pygame.gfxdraw.circle) can draw a thin, antialiased circle.

---

You can try to stitch the circle with a `pygame.draw.circle()` for the body and `pygame.gfxdraw.circle()` on the edges. However, the quality is low and can depend on the system:

```py
def drawAACircle(surf, color, center, radius, width):
    pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(surf, *center, 100, color)  
    pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(surf, *center, 100-width, color)  
    pygame.draw.circle(surf, color, center, radius, width)
```

---

I recommend drawing a image with an antialiased circle and *blit* the image. You can create the image using OpenCV ([opencv-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)). See [OpenCV - Drawing Functions](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html).

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import cv2
import numpy

def drawAACircle(surf, color, center, radius, width):
    circle_image = numpy.zeros((radius*2+4, radius*2+4, 4), dtype = numpy.uint8)
    circle_image = cv2.circle(circle_image, (radius+2, radius+2), radius-width//2, (*color, 255), width, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)  
    circle_surface = pygame.image.frombuffer(circle_image.flatten(), (radius*2+4, radius*2+4), 'RGBA')
    surf.blit(circle_surface, circle_surface.get_rect(center = center))

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill((32, 32, 32))
    drawAACircle(window, (255, 0, 0), window.get_rect().center, 100, 20)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

Another approach is to construct the circle with [`numpy.fromfunction`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html):

```py
f_circle = lambda i, j: numpy.clip(radius - numpy.hypot(i-radius-1, j-radius-1), 0, 1) * 255
circle_alpha = numpy.fromfunction(f_circle, shape).astype(numpy.uint8)
```

The following function creates a completely filled anti-aliased circle with a specified radius and color:

```py
import pygame
import numpy

def drawAACircle(surf, color, center, radius):
    f_circle = lambda i, j: numpy.clip(radius - numpy.hypot(i-radius-1, j-radius-1), 0, 1) * 255
    shape = (radius*2+4, radius*2+4)
    circle_rgb = numpy.full((*shape, len(color)), color, dtype = numpy.uint8)
    circle_alpha = numpy.fromfunction(f_circle, shape).astype(numpy.uint8).reshape((*shape, 1))
    circle_array = numpy.concatenate((circle_rgb, circle_alpha), 2)
    circle_surface = pygame.image.frombuffer(circle_array.flatten(), shape, 'RGBA')
    surf.blit(circle_surface, circle_surface.get_rect(center = center))
```

[image]